Show that a sequence converges to $0$
I want to solve this exercise:

Let $K$ be a real number strictly greater than $1$, and $\epsilon_n$ be a sequence of positive real numbers converging to $0$. Let $(u_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers from $[0, 1]$ satisfying:
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \quad 
0 \leq u_{n+1} \leq \frac{u_n +\epsilon_n\ }{K}.
$$
Does the sequence $(u_n)$ converge to $0$?

Here is my approach:
Let $A = \{u_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. We know that $A$ is bounded below, so $\inf(A)$ exists.
So we have 2 cases: $\inf(A) = 0$, so there exists a subsequence of $(u_n)$ that converges to $0$. Let $U(\phi_n)$ be the sequence that converge to $0$. We have
$$ 
U(\phi_{n+1}) \leq \frac{U(\phi_n) + \epsilon_n}{K} 
$$
So $U(\phi_{n+1})$ converges to $0$. So we can show by induction that $U(\phi_{n+p})$ converge to $0$, so $(u_n)$ converges to $0$.
For the sake of contradiction, let's suppose that $\alpha = \inf(A) > 0$:
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \quad 
u_{n+1} - u_n  \leq \frac{(1-K)\cdot\alpha + \epsilon_n}{K}.
$$
For $N$ large enough, we have
$$ 
\forall n \geq N, \quad 
\varepsilon_n < (K - 1) \cdot \alpha
$$
so
$$ 
\forall n \geq N, \quad 
\varepsilon_n - (K - 1) \cdot \alpha < 0, 
$$
so
$$ 
\forall n \geq N, \quad 
u_{n+1} - u_n < 0. 
$$
Thus, $u_n$ is decreasing for large enough $N$, so $u_n$ converges to $\alpha$, so
$$ 
\alpha \leq \frac{\alpha}{K}
$$
which is a contradiction for $K > 0$.
Is my solution correct?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I’m sorry, can’t you apply the comparison test directly with the sequence $\epsilon_n$?

@Malady I didn't undertand can you please  give more details

$+1$ because this is a nice question.

If you are familar with Upper and lower limits, it will be easy to deal your question.
Let $$a=\limsup_{n\to\infty} u_n,\quad b=\liminf_{n\to\infty} u_n,$$
by the inequalities $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \quad 
0 \leq u_{n+1} \leq \frac{u_n +\epsilon_n\ }{K},$$
we can get $$0\leq a\leq\frac{a}{K},\quad 0\leq b\leq\frac{b}{K}$$
since $K>1$, we must have $a=b=0$.
Hence $$\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n=0.$$

Suppose $u_n\not\to 0.$
Since $u_n\in [0,1]$ and $u_n\not\to 0,\ l:=\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty} u_n \in (0,1]$ exists. Furthermore, as a consequence of the definition of $\limsup,$ there exists infinitely many $n_1<n_2<n_3<\ldots$ such that $\frac{l}{\sqrt[4]{K}} < u_{n_j}< l\sqrt[4]{K}\ \forall\ j\in\mathbb{N}.$
Next, $\exists\ N$ such that $\epsilon_n < \frac{(\sqrt{K}-1)l }{\sqrt{K}}\ \forall\ n\geq N.$ So, $\ \exists\ J$ such that $n_J>N,\implies \epsilon_{n_J} < \frac{(\sqrt{K}-1)l }{\sqrt{K}} < (\sqrt{K}-1) u_{n_J},$ because $u_{n_J}>\frac{l}{\sqrt{K}}.$ [Furthermore, note also (for later on in the proof) that $\epsilon_{n_J+p} < (\sqrt{K}-1) u_{n_J}\ \forall\ p\geq 1$ ].
Next, we show by induction on $p$ that $ u_{n_J+p}\leq \frac{u_{n_J}}{\sqrt{K}}\ \forall\ p\geq 1.$ Basis case $(p=1):$
$\Large{u_{n_J+1} \leq \frac{u_{n_J + \epsilon_{n_J}}}{K}} < \frac{u_{n_J} + (\sqrt{K} -1) u_{n_J}}{K} = \frac{u_{n_J}}{\sqrt{K}}.$
Induction step: Suppose $ u_{n_J+p}\leq \frac{u_{n_J}}{\sqrt{K}}$ for some $p\geq 1.$ Then,
$${u_{n_J+(p+1)} \leq \frac{u_{n_J+p} + \epsilon_{n_J+p}}{K} \leq \frac{ \frac{u_{n_J}}{\sqrt{K}} + (\sqrt{K}-1) u_{n_J} }{K} = \frac{ \left({\sqrt{K}} -1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{K}}\right) u_{n_J} }{K}  < \frac{ u_{n_J}{\sqrt{K}} }{K} }. $$
This finishes the induction proof. Therefore, $ u_{n_{J+1}}\leq \frac{u_{n_J}}{\sqrt{K}} < \frac{l\sqrt[4]{K}}{\sqrt{K}} = \frac{l}{\sqrt[4]{K}},$ contradicting the fact that $u_{n_{J+1}} > \frac{l}{\sqrt[4]{K}}.$ Due to this contradiction, we conclude that $u_n\to 0.$
